# Changing default export FromCollection to FromView Maatwebsite\Excel Laravel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

Is there a way to make it such that when we call `php artisan make:export`, the default export file generated implements `FromView` and not `FromCollection`?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/blob/3.1/src/Console/stubs/export.model.stub
If you need to change it, you can publish with `vendor:publish` and set it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can do that by editing `stubs`. You can follow these steps:

1. Run `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider"` to publish assets.
2. Open `stubs/export.plain.stub` file and replace the following code.

```php
<?php

namespace DummyNamespace;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;

class DummyClass implements FromView
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
    */
    public function view(): View
    {
        //
    }
}
```

3. Now try again with `php artisan make:export`

Answer (score 0):

if you need collection you need to import its :

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
```

and

```
class EntityExport implements WithMapping
```

and using like thats :

```
public function map($row): array
{
    return [
        $row->id,
        $row->title ? $row->title : '-',
        $row->name ? $row->name : '-',
    ];
}
```